# How can I specify a team/game active record relationship?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Rails Version: 4.2.0
OS: Windows 7

Hello, I asked a similar question a few days ago, but some stuff went wrong.
I want to track games, each game has two teams and both team's scores.

My original plan to solve this was to use a join model called **Match**.
my models looked like this

**Team**

```
has_many :matches
has_many :games, through: :matches
```

**Game**

```
has_many :matches
has_many :teams, through: :matches
```

**Match**

```
belongs_to :team
belongs_to :game
```

I quickly became confused on something: How can I store scores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you rename match to something like "game_participations" to reduce confusion. Then you would put any info that is specific to each team for each game (e.g. shots on goal by team A in match B) in the join table( game_participations) and data that is about the match itself (e.g. names of the referees) in the games table